# Powershell Regex Query

Tags: regex, string, powershell

I'm having some issues pulling the desired values from my source string.

I have 2 possible string formats (that I'm differentiating based on a -match operation and if check):

```
{u'specialGroup': u'projectWriters', u'role': u'WRITER'
```

or

```
, {u'role': u'WRITER', u'userByEmail': u'john@domain.com'
```

What I desire to return from the regex:

```
[0]projectWriters

[1]WRITER
```

and

```
[0]WRITER

[1]john@domain.com
```

Basically I need to return all values between start string `: u'` and end string `'` as array values [0] and [1] but cannot figure out the regex pattern.

Trying:

```
[regex]::match($stuff[1], ": u'([^']+)'").groups

Groups   : {: u'WRITER', WRITER}    
Success  : True
Captures : {: u'WRITER'}
Index    : 10
Length   : 11
Value    : : u'WRITER'



Success  : True
Captures : {WRITER}
Index    : 14
Length   : 6
Value    : WRITER
```

But no sign of `john@domain.com` value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A pragmatic approach, assuming that all strings have the same field structure:

```
$strings = "{u'specialGroup': u'projectWriters', u'role': u'WRITER'}",
           ", {u'role': u'WRITER', u'userByEmail': u'john@domain.com'"

$strings | ForEach-Object { ($_ -split 'u''|''' -notmatch '[{}:,]')[1,3] }
```

yields:

```
projectWriters
WRITER
WRITER
john@domain.com
```

---

As for what you tried:

`[regex]::match()` only ever returns *one* match, so you need to base your solution on `[regex]::matches()` - plural! - which returns *all* matches, and then extract the capture-group values of interest.

```
$strings | ForEach-Object { [regex]::matches($_, ": u'([^']+)'").Groups[1,3].Value }
```